# Gitlab ci issue with parent and child POM

Tags: maven, microservices, gitlab-ci

I have 6 microservices in my project and i have seperated them into 6 projects in gitlab. When i tried to build this microservices all together or after building parent POM later child POM seperately outside Gitlab it is working but while using gitlab-ci i am not able to build it as they are failing non resolvable parent POM.Can someone please let me know how can i build this microservices independently(building parent POM and keeping the artifact available for all other projects).

Tried caching and artifacts in gitlab but they are strightly bound to single project

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to build those six microservices together, put them into one multi-module project. Then you have one project on GitLab and everything will be much easier.

If you need to separate, then you need a Maven package manager. You can use the one that is included in GitLab, or you can use an external one like Artifactory.